# Find the smallest alldifferent array whose sum is n

Tags: minizinc

This seems like such a simple problem, but I can't find a simple way to represent this in MiniZinc.

```minizinc
include "globals.mzn";

int: target;
int: max_length;

var 1..max_length: length;

array[1..length] of int: t;

constraint sum(t) = target;
constraint alldifferent(t);

solve minimize length;
```

This program errors with:
``` MiniZinc: type error: type-inst must be par set but is ``var set of int' ```

Is there a clean/simple way to represent this problem in MiniZinc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays in MiniZinc have a fixed size. The compiler is therefore saying that `array[1..length] of int: t` is not allowed, because `length` is a variable.

The alternative that MiniZinc offers is arrays with **optional** types, these are values that might exist. This means that when you write something like `[t | t in 1..length]`, it will actually give you an array of `1..maxlength`, but some elements can be marked as `absent`/`<>`.

For this particular problem you are also overlooking the fact that `t` should itself be a array of variables. The values of `t` are not yet known when at compile-time. A better way to formulate this problem would thus be to allow the values of `t` to be `0` when they are beyond the chosen length:

```
include "globals.mzn";

int: target;
int: max_length;

var 1..max_length: length;

array[1..max_length] of var int: t;

constraint sum(t) = target;
constraint alldifferent_except_0(t);
constraint forall(i in length+1..max_length) (t[i] = 0);

solve minimize length;
```

The next step to improve the model would be to ensure that the initial domain of `t` makes sense and instead of being all different, forcing an ordering would be equivalent, but eliminate some symmetry in the possible solutions.